# Reserved keywords in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, compiler-construction, grammar, keyword

At the CocoaHeads Öresund meeting yesterday, [peylow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165059/peylow) had constructed a great ObjC quiz. The competition was intense and three people were left with the same score when the final question was to be evaluated: How many reserved keywords does Objective-C add to C?

Some spirited debate followed. All agreed that `@interface`, `@implementation` etc are all pre-processor directives rather than keywords, but how about something like `in`? It might be a keyword, but it's not a *reserved* keyword. For example, the following will compile without errors or warnings:

```
NSArray* in;
for (in in in)
   NSLog(@"bwahahaa");
```

We concluded that ObjC adds **no** reserved keywords to C, and someone won a seemingly well-earned book.

But today I tried some more systematic abuse on the compiler by trying things like this:

```
int self = 45;
self++;
int y = self;
```

That compiles fine, and the same code works replacing self for `BOOL, bycopy, inout, oneway, byref, SEL,` and `IMP`.

Using `id` as the variable name, the first and last lines compile, but not the second one. The same goes for `Protocol`, and `Class`.

Using `super`, the first line compiles, but not the second and third.

With `YES`, `NO`, and `NULL`, all three lines fail to compile, probably because they are just defined as `true`, `false`, and `nil`.

It looks to me like a lot of this is gcc getting confused and I'm not so sure it reflects what is and isn't a reserved keyword in Objective-C. Why, for example, is it ok to use `self` as the name of an int, but not `super`?

The fact that the first assignment always works (except for with YES, NO, and NULL) would seem to support the idea that none of the candidates are technically reserved keywords that are not found in C. Or?

Could someone please give us an authoritative explication of this thorny issue?

Several people's honor is at stake.

EDIT: As Nikolai Ruhe pointed out, we need a clear definition of "keyword" to proceed. Niko cited a Wikipedia article saying that a keyword is "a word or identifier that has a particular meaning".

I think it is reasonable to use this definition from the same article:

> In many languages, such as C and
>   similar environments like C++, a
>   keyword is a reserved word which
>   identifies a syntactic form. Words
>   used in control flow constructs, such
>   as if, then, and else are keywords. In
>   these languages, keywords cannot also
>   be used as the names of variables or
>   functions.

Furthermore, as the article states:

> Typically, when a programmer attempts
>   to use a keyword for a variable or
>   function name, a compilation error
>   will be triggered.

In this sense, then, are there any reserved keywords that are [predefined in the language’s formal specifications and cannot be used as a user-defined name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word)?

Comment: Some related material here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c

Answer (score 10):

*All agreed that @interface, @implementation etc are all pre-processor directives rather than keywords*

Then all were mistaken. `#import`  and `#pragma` are preprocessor directives.
 `@interface, @implementation, @protocol` and so forth are keywords of Objective-C, and they are *compiler* directives.  They haven't been preprocessor directives since NeXT extended GCC to compile Objective-C without a Stepstone's original Objective-C pre-processor implementation.

Comment: Then that would mean that @interface is a keyword (in the sense stated in the edit above) but id isn't, because the compiler refuses to compile eg "int @interface = 1;" but happily uses id as the name for an int. But then again, the compiler also doesn't allow "int @icecream = 1;". So where does that leave us?
#import -- preprocessor directive
@interface -- compiler directive
@ -- reserved character
id/self/in -- special meaning in some contexts but not reserved

Comment: id is a typedef.  You can find it in objc.h

Answer (score 4):

Re: Nikolai Ruhe's suggest that self is a keyword

`self` is a parameter to an Objective-C method of type `id` (similar to how `_cmd` is also a param, of type `SEL`) and not a keyword. `nil` is a macro which expands to `NULL`. I'm a little disappointed that `super` doesn't expand to a macro, nor is it a parameter.

From the wikipedia entry:

> Objective-C is a thin layer on top of C, and moreover is a strict superset of C. It is possible to compile any C program with an Objective-C compiler, and to freely include C code within an Objective-C class.

That would preclude Objective-C from adding any restricted keywords to the language.

Comment: That's a very good point, although the restriction is apparently not fully respected by gcc.

Comment: The conclusion is not true. A superset of a language can add keywords by using terms that are illegal in the original language. And that’s exactly what Objective-C does.

Comment: Regarding `super` not being a macro: The compiler must be able to recognize `super` since it has to use the correct messaging type (calling `objc_msgSendSuper` instead of `objc_msgSend`). `super` points to the same object as `self`, so there no much point in making it another argument also.

Comment: Objective-C being a superset does not preclude it from adding additional restricted keywords, but allowing all C programs to compile with an Objective-C compiler does.

Comment: @jon: Why? Objective-C does add keywords, as NSResponder pointed out. But the compiler also compiles all C programs.

Comment: @jon: B.t.w: The implicit `self` argument of instance methods is not of type `id` but statically typed to the class.

Comment: @Nikolai: I think what jon means is that a C program with a variable called super, which will compile under C, will not be accepted by an Objective-C compiler (at least not gcc), an in this respect it seems that seems to break the strict superset requirement.

Comment: @Felixyz: Using `super` as a name for a variable in a C function is compiling fine in gcc4.0, gcc4.2, and clang. Using it in a method is of course an error. No requirement broken. And what I meant was that jon’s reasoning is wrong: A strict superset **can** add keywords to a language without breaking anything.

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe: I concede your point: whether super can be used as a variable name inside a method is not important, as long as it compiles in a C function, which it does. And @ is not a valid character in C identifiers, so not allowing @interface etc as variable names doesn't break the strict superset requirement either.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_(computer_programming)) defines keywords as:

> In computer programming, a keyword is a word or identifier that has a particular meaning to the programming language.

I'd translate that to: a keyword in a language is a non-terminal in its grammar. (Btw, the grammar doesn't contain the word "keyword" just by itself, so no confusion there).

The terminals in the [grammar](http://objc.toodarkpark.net/grammar.html) would be:

- void
- char
- short
- int
- long
- float
- double
- signed
- unsigned
- id
- const
- volatile
- in
- out
- inout
- bycopy
- byref
- oneway
- self
- super
- @interface
- @end
- @implementation
- @end
- @interface
- @end
- @implementation
- @end
- @protoco
- @end
- @class

Comment: The question is which reserved keywords ObjC might **add** to C. As you can see in the examples, you are free to use "in" as the name of a variable so it clearly doesn't count as a reserved keyword.

Comment: I mean, the fact that "int float = 45;" fails to compile while "int id = 45;" compiles fine tells us something.

Comment: they aren't "examples". It's the complete list, as far as I can see. And well, it depends on what you'd like to call a keyword. I gave you my answer to that question.

Comment: I meant the example code in the question. "a keyword in a language is a non-terminal". Did you mean "terminal"? I don't think anyone would call #define a keyword, so why should we @interface? Thanks for the offering, but I'm not convinced. To me, anything that can be used as the name of a variable can't very well be a (reserved) keyword.

Comment: @Felixyz: It seems that as a prerequisite to answer your question it is important to (generally) define the term keyword. Only then can be answered what is a keyword in the case of Objective-C. Obviously there are differing opinions on that.

Answer (score 2):

Grammar in [Appendix B of the original 1995 book](http://www.cilinder.be/docs/next/NeXTStep/3.3/nd/Concepts/ObjectiveC/B_Grammar/Grammar.htmld/index.html) defines `super` as "literal symbol" terminal and it's a special-case in message *receiver* syntax.

`in` literal symbol is part of *protocol-qualifier* in ObjC 1.0 and was reused in fast enumeration syntax in ObjC 2.0 (which has no formal grammar definition AFAIK).

`id` is defined as part of *type-specifier* alongside `void`, `char`, `unsigned`, typedefed types, etc. If you call `void` a keyword, then `id` is too.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the [Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocLanguageSummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH3-TPXREF102) gives you some clues about what is possible or not. As some "keywords" are defined in a header file, their substitution can lead to observed (and unexpected) behavior.

Comment: Right. So the question is: are there *any* bona fide reserved keywords in Objective-C (beyond those already reserved in C).

Comment: There are no reserved keywords like in other languages sense. It is more like defines that can interact badly with your code. It all depends on the pre-processor work.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocLanguageSummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH3-TPXREF103).

As far as I can tell, that document doesn't classify anything as a "reserved word". The `@implementation`, `@interface`, etc. are called "compiler directives."