# Parsing a string with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

How to parse an xcode url and get data that returns i.e

> 1
>
> bilal
>
> engineer

to different xcode fields i.e

```
NSString *id=1
NSString *name=bilal
NSString *designation=engineer
```

note. my url is self constructed to simply return the fields

Comment: What's an "xcode url", out of curiosity?

Comment: result = [NSString stringWithFormat: "http://dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php?mode=login&u=global6@evsoft.pk&p=123456"];
it's something like that man

Comment: http://dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php?mode=login&u=global6@evsoft.pk&p=123456
how do you think i can get the values of u and p from the above string in xcode????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are already establishing a connection to your web service or not… if not look up NSURLConnection in Google or Stack Overflow.

Regarding the only part of your question that I understood:

```
NSString* result = @"1\nbilal\nengineer";
NSArray* components = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSString* id = [components objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* name = [components objectAtIndex:1];
NSString* designation = [components objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: `id` is not a keyword in Objective-C. It’s a type name and, since types are in a different name space than the name space for variables, `id` is also a valid variable name.

Comment: Oops you're right, I removed that bit of misinformation from my answer.

Comment: yes i know that about id.. i was just explaining my requiremnt

Comment: @Bavarious, that's not quite true. Yes, `id` is a type, but according to [this page](http://tinyurl.com/63y49sn) it's also a reserved word. That makes sense because `id` has some special behavior. It's a built-in type that can be used in place of any object pointer type, and when you use it you're basically saying "I don't care about the type."

Comment: http://dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php?mode=login&u=global6@evsoft.pk&p=123456
how do you think i can get the values of u and p from the above string in xcode????????

Comment: you gave the right answer thanks.. i don't know what i was thnking
lol
resolved

Comment: @Caleb I’d say that document is misleading. If that were true, `id id;` wouldn’t be valid in Objective-C — and it is valid.

Comment: @Caleb Also, that document says that `name` is a reserved word. O_o There must be some context I’m missing — if that document is talking about mapping a DOM type to an Objective-C class then I agree that `id` is reserved but in the sense that any other type is reserved. But, then again, `name` is not a Foundation or Cocoa class name. Odd.

Comment: Interesting question on SO regarding Objective-C keywords: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873630/reserved-keywords-in-objective-c