# id as a name of property in NSManagedObject-subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am making some improvements in project made by my predecessors on current job. I found property `id` in `NSManagedObject` class as shown below:

[image]

Also `Xcode` highlights this property name as id type. Can this cause some problems in future? I mean, does system smart enough to understand that this is a property name? Do I need to rename it through refactor or just let it stay as is?

Comment: bad idea. it works but.. dont do it

Comment: I don't, it's the legacy of my predecessors in existing project

Answer (score 3):

`id` is a [reserved word in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873630/reserved-keywords-in-objective-c), do not use any reserved words as property names on an object.

Comment: using works but is confusing to the user -- so I agree with ryan -- dont

Comment: It's completely legal to use in this way, though.

Comment: @RyanR, thanks, I know. Question is do I need to refactor it or not

Comment: Thanks, @TomHarrington! Looks like you're right. Even if it is not correct logically it is not affect harmful at functionality

Comment: @Alex, you don't *need* to, but it's probably less confusing in the long run if you do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `id` in your model prefer `uid` for example even if the compiler can distinguish the difference it is not a good practice.