# Purpose of @ Symbol Before Strings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been using Objective-C for a while now, but have never really understood what the purpose of the @ symbol before all strings is. For instance, why do you have to declare a string like this:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a string";
```

and not like this:

```
NSString *anotherString = "This is another string";
```

as you do in Java or so many other programming languages. Is there a good reason?

Comment: See [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It denotes a NSString (rather than a standard C string)

an NSString is an Object that stores a unicode string and provides a bunch of method to assist with manipulating.

a C string is just a \0 terminated bunch of characters (bytes).

EDIT: and the good reason is that Objective-C builds on top of C, the C language constructs need to be still available. @"" is an objective-c only extension.

Comment: When you see an @ in front of something in ObjC, it's a good sign that it's part of the extension ObjC makes to C.  @interface, @implementation, @protocol, @selector, @class, etc.  @ is sort of the informal Objective-C namespace.  It's similar to how everything in Cocoa is prefixed with 'NS' so that it won't tend to conflict with other stuff going on.