# Why is the '@' used before strings in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purpose of @ Symbol Before Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446308/purpose-of-symbol-before-strings)

I've been curious to what `@` means before every string is objective C. Is it easier on the compiler, or more efficient in some way?

Example:

```
NSString* flavour = @"Chocolate"
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25749/542425

Comment: "The @ sign is used often in Objective-C to denote extentions to the language." src- http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

Answer (score 18):

`@"Chocolate"` is just a shortcut to create an `NSString` instance. You could also use:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"Chocolate"];
```

If you didn't use the @ you would create a C string (`char` array).

Answer (score 7):

The `@` character isn't used in C or C++ identifiers, so it's used to introduce Objective-C language keywords in a way that won't conflict with the other languages' keywords. This enables the "Objective" part of the language to freely intermix with the C or C++ part.

Comment: You can see its other uses in things like `@interface`, `@implementation`, `@property`, `@synthesize`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Because Objective-C is a superset of plain C, there has to be a way to distinguish `NSString` literals plain C strings (which are basically just `char*` pointers).

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate between c strings and the objective-c classe I think