# Swift: Placeholder for current configuration

Tags: swift, placeholder

I'm reading an [example](http://appfoundry.be/blog/2014/07/04/Xcode-Env-Configuration/) for having multiple configs and accessing the active one at runtime with this Objective C code:

```
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"plist"];
  NSDictionary *config = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

What is the Swift equivalent of `@"Configuration"` to get the active Configuration value?

This doesn't work:

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(@"Configuration", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
```

Comment: You don't need the symbol `@` just use "Configuration". Also, you need to make sure there's a file called `Configuration.plist` added to the build resources.

Comment: In this example Configuration is one of three possible String literals (Debug, Release, AdHoc) where one is active based on your Scheme/Configuration (I think).  So "Configuration" doesn't appear to be the way to go.

Comment: Nope, if you read the original article carefully, all of the three files are called `Configuration.plist`. They are just in different folders and will be dynamically added to runtime based on the _Xcode configuration_ as well as the _scheme_ you choose.

Comment: Got it now, thanks!  Totally misread that.  I saw the @ sign and thought it was something different but just read this is how Strings can be denoted in Objective C - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446308/purpose-of-symbol-before-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `@` and it will work:

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Configuration", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
```

Comment: Does this treat "Configuration" as a literal value or as something that should be dynamically determined?   It should be the latter (see my comment on the question).