# What does the @ symbol mean for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I know the following uses of @ (at symbol):

@"myString" - is used to indicate an objective-c NSString, rather than a standard C string

@keyword - used to identify some objective c keywords such as @implementation, @synthesize, @class and @interface

What does @KEYNAME mean in the context below?

```
[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:@KEYNAME andPassword:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:b64data] forServiceName:@"default" updateExisting:YES error:&ter_ror];
```

Does @ have any other possible meanings?

Comment: Where does that code come from?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that it's a custom macro.

Comment: actually, if KEYNAME is #DEFINE'd to be a normal c-style string literal, the @ just turns it into an obj-C NSString literal, just like @"myString".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means nothing at all in the context of your code snippet. That will fail with a syntax error.

The reason @ is used in Obj-C keywords and in constant strings is because @ is not a valid character to use as part of a token in C, and Obj-C is a strict superset of C. This means that all valid C code is valid Obj-C code, so Obj-C can't take any keywords that could have possibly shown up in valid C. Since @ isn't valid in tokens, that means Obj-C could simply use it to start all of its keywords and not worry about collisions.

As for other possible meanings, there are a few keywords you omitted, such as `@protocol`, `@dynamic`, `@private`, `@protected`, `@public`, `@selector`, and `@encode`.

Comment: It's not a syntax error if you have `#define KEYWORD "a string"`.  There's also `@package` and `@compatibility_alias`.

Comment: @Dave: It was defined as a string