# What does @ mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

I see a lot of keywords prefixed with the @ symbol in Objective-C. At a high level what does @ mean?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25749/620197

Answer (score 1):

The `@` character doesn't mean anything *by itself*, except that it is used in front of many Objective-C specific keywords so that they are not confused with regular C identifiers.