# Why does NSString use an @?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

Here's one of those questions that you never really ask yourself. I've programmed in Objective-C for a fair amount of time, so I'm not asking how to use a NSString.  It's just one of those things that's always been "that's how it's done", or if the question was ever asked, I don't remember the answer.

My first thought was that it is used to distinguish the NSString literal from a CString, but NSString's class reference states "NSString is implemented to represent an array of Unicode characters, in other words, a text string".  So if it represents an array of characters, then what exactly is the @ for?

Comment: Let me know if that isn't what you meant.

Comment: Here you'll find your answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c

Comment: Great, somehow I managed not to find those when I searched.

Comment: Google for "objective c at symbol" and the link I gave is the first hit.  The problem I had when I first searched for this (several months ago) was I made it string specific.

Comment: I think it is as you guessed anyway. "abc" is a c type string and @"abc" is an NSString object representing "abc". Give it a try with NSLog. For "abc" you can use c-style printf formats and for @"abc" you can use %@ in the format string.

Comment: @mydogisbox Yeah, I made my search string specific and was also using the '@' itself, which of course turned up a bunch of examples and pretty much everything related to NSStrings in general.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that `@` now (or soon, anyway) also introduces other object literals like numbers, dictionaries, and arrays.