# What does @[] stand for in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've come across the @[] in the following context

```
self.searches = [@[] mutableCopy];
```

What is it?

Comment: That looks like a bit of an abuse of the new array literal notation.  I'd go with `self.searches = [NSMutableArray array];` (which I think is clearer and also doesn't leak in manual referencing counting.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an array literal.  In another words: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]` in short form.
You can add objects in it like this

```
NSArray *array = @[@"one", @"two"];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
self.searches = [[NSArray array] mutableCopy];
```