# objective-c strings: why don't you need a setter/getter?

Tags: objective-c

I'm just beginning, and I'm a little hung up on this. I may have a fundamental misunderstanding with which you can kindly help me out.

Why is it that you can assign a string value to an NSString* (and, I'm sure, many other object types) directly? E.g.,

> NSString* s = @"Hello, world!";

whereas the following code, I believe, would assign to s2 s1's *pointer* value (and therefore only incidentally provide s2 with a string value)?

> NSString* s1 = @"Hello, world!";
>
> NSString* s2 = s1;

For many objects, don't you have to indicate a property, a.k.a. instance variable, to which you want to assign a value (i.e., use a setter method)? Shouldn't the object itself accept assignments only of pointer values? Or do classes such as NSString automatically reinterpret code such as the first example above to assign the indicated string to an implied instance variable using an implied setter?

Comment: String is so common that it is usually given special treatment in a programming language.

Comment: In addition to Perception's answer you may want to look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constant-string-objects.html) for additional information on how Constant Strings are handled in ObjC.

Comment: thank you, all of these responses are helpful, though i'm not allowed to vote up yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it that you can assign a string value to an NSString* (and, I'm
>   sure, many other object types) directly?

Though it may look like it, you are not assigning the value of the string 'directly' to the instance variable. You are actually assigning the address of the string value to your instance variable. Now, the real question is what is going on behind the scenes when you have an expression of the type:

```
NSString * str = @"Hello World";
```

This expression represents the creation of a *string literal*. In C (and Objective-C which is a strict superset of C), string literals get special handling. Specifically, the following happens:

1. When your code is compiled the string "Hello World" will be created in the data section of
   the program.
2. When the program is executing, an instance variable 'str' will be allocated on the heap.
3. The 'str' instance variable will be pointed at the static memory location where the actual string "Hello World" is stored.

The main difference between your first and second examples is that in the second example the memory for the string variable is dynamically allocated on the heap, at runtime. Note that in both cases the variable 'str' is just a pointer allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

More or less the latter.  String literals like `@"Hello World!"` are treated as a special case in Objective-C: strings declared with that syntax are statically allocated, instantiated and cached at compile time to improve performance.  From the programmer's perspective, it's no different from calling `[NSString stringWithString:@"Hello World!"]` or a constructor that takes a C-string -- you should just think of it as syntactic sugar.

FWIW, Objective-C has recently begun extending the `@` prefix to allow declaring dictionary and array literals as well, e.g.: `@{ @"key" : @"value" }` or `@[ obj1, obj2, obj3 ]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function of the compiler and not a language construct. The compiler in this case recognizes a string literal and inserts some code to produce the intended result.

@"" is essentially shorthand for NSString's +stringWithUTF8String method.

take from here:
[What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *s1 = @"Hello, world!";
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Hello, world!"];
```

The former allocates a new NSString object statically (instead of on the heap at runtime, as the latter would do).

It's important to note that these are just pointers. When you do `NSString *s2 = s1`, both `s1` and `s2` refer to the same object.

Comment: This is incorrect. String literals are not allocated on the heap.