# What does the "at sign" @ mean in this objective C code

Tags: objective-c, at-sign

I have been using Objective C for quite a few years but I didn't know @ sign can be used like this (line 6 inside the for loop):

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeInteger:mti forKey:@"mti"];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        [arr addObject:@(mt[i])];
    [coder encodeObject:arr forKey:@"mt"];
}
```

What does it mean? surprisingly I can remove it and the compiler does not complain and the code looks like working fine?!

This is part of MTRandom https://github.com/preble/MTRandom/blob/master/MTRandom/MTRandom.m#L115

Comment: It' a new notation -- creates an NSNumber.  There are also similar notations to create NSArrays and NSDictionaries.

Comment: You can also now use `[]` to index an NSArray or find an object in an NSDictionary.

Comment: And here is some documentation: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the @ operator converts a C numeric value (int, long, float, double, etc) into an instance of NSNumber. It's most often used with numeric literals (eg @3.5), but also applies to expressions as in your example.

This enhancement to the Objective-C language was introduced with Xcode 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's a new syntax for boxing values with less typing. Assuming `mt[i]` is a numeric type, `@(mt[i])` places it in an `NSNumber` object.

Answer (score 1):

This is new to objective-C it turns the primitive integer into an NSNumber, there are also equivalents for NSArrays @(..) and NSDictionary @{...}