# What's with the @ sign in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

I'm an ANSI C expert, taking my first steps to learn Objective C.

How should I think of/read the "@" that crops up everywhere?

At first, I thought of it as a compiler directive - "this in an instruction to the compiler to generate getter/setter" for "@synthesize someProperty".

But the "@" before strings doesn't seem to fit that model, and seems basically redundant.

Also would be glad of any advice for C experts on "how to quickly learn Objective C".   Thanks,

Peter

Comment: I think the @-sign is used because ObjC is an extension to the C language and making use of this sign would prevent any issues with existing C code.

Comment: try **[this](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww&authuser=0#hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&authuser=0&site=webhp&q=objective+c+developer+reference&oq=objective+c+developer+reference&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0j0i10i30j0i30l5j0i8i30j0i30.14895.15276.3.15572.4.4.0.0.0.0.88.289.4.4.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.qFHQ53UaAYo&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&bvm=bv.41642243,d.ZGU&fp=1d98386d32127408&biw=1842&bih=964)**, it can help you...

Answer (score -1):

`@` is just a character unless you use it with full context

```
@interface //For declaring a class
@property // For creating a property
@synthesize // For synthesising property 
@implementation //For implementing a class
@end //For ending @interface or @implementation
@"Some String" //Represents a string
@try
@catch
```

and so on.

So simple `@` is nothing but when combined it becomes the directive

Comment: They're not keywords.  Every last one of those is a compiler directive

Comment: ...and @[obj1, obj2, ...], or @{ key1 : value1, key2 : value2, ...}, or @(12) or @(FALSE)... etc. they are just instructions for the complier nothing more.

Comment: @holex yes they are added recently :)

Comment: @holex Boxing is an ObjC extension to it's own language that encapsulates literals or other objects inside of objects or collections.  That first one expands out to `static NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]`