# @ notation in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

What is the meaning of `@` notation in `Objective-C` ?
Ex: `self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];`

Comment: You could have Google'd / searched on StackOverflow for that question. [This answer is very detailed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c).

Comment: Google? But SO has a search field too. Why not use that??!!

Answer (score 2):

These are `literals` that you may use since Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0 / clang v3.1. For a detailed overview, see [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Answer (score 0):

@ is the sigil for compiler directives. 
(Basically macros)

In your example you see the syntax for an NSArray Literal.

@[ elementObject, anotherElementObject, ...];