# What does it mean when you put an @ before an integer in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-literals

What does it mean when you put an `@` before an integer in Objective-C?
Like so:

```
@4
```

Comment: It makes it an ```NSNumber```.

Comment: See "NSNumber Literals" in http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html.

Comment: Note that this is a relatively new compiler feature, so many books and other references will not discuss it.  It goes with the notation of `@[a,b,c]` for an NSArray and several other enhancements, as shown in Martin R's link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 7):

It is the `NSNumber` literal. A shortcut for this:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:4];
```

Comment: Do you know its equivalent in swift 2.3 and swift 3.0?

Comment: You should probably use the Swift numeric types instead, like Int, Float etc. If you really need to use NSNumber in Swift, you can do it like this: `var num = NSNumber(value: 4)`