# Objective-C at sign and curly braces, @{ ... } what does it mean?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-literals

I have this line in Objective-C.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray;
[mutableArray addObject:@{ @"Something" : aObject, @"Otherthing" : anotherObject }];
```

What does the `@{ ... }` part do exactly? It is an object, but it seems to create some kind of key, value pair on the fly.

Comment: First Google result: http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/nsdictionary-literals-in-objective-c.html

Comment: @NathanAldenSr I think this is beyond a simple google search, unless you actually know what it is called/is your not going to get very good google results. I googled the meaning of it and got that link but then dummed it down to what a newbie may search for and didn't get anything close to what this actually is.

Comment: True, if only I knew the right question?... tried a couple of keywords in google and couldn't get it to display the right stuff. I knew it was there.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It was the first Google result for the phrase *nsdictionary shorthand*. I should've been more specific.

Comment: OH... now I learn something new... this is the "shorthand" way to create an NSdictionary! Great. Thanks!

Comment: And you can use `@[value, value, value]` to create an NSArray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the @ symbol represent in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is creating NSDictionary object as you said. Syntax is simple

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = @{key: object, key: object};
```

In your example, keys are objects of NSString class. It is important to remember that dictionary copies keys and retains values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you elaborate on the last part... what do you mean it "copies" keys and "retains" values. I think i get the "retain" part, I'm thinking it just increases the retain count on the value object and stores a reference to it. From this I deduce that on the key side it is doing the opposite? Why this?

Comment: Copy means just what it says. It creates an immutable copy of the key objects in case they're mutable, and subsequently change, which would be a bad thing. This does mean that the keys used in an NSDictionary must implement the NSCopying protocol.

Answer (score 3):

These are called Literals. Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0 and above can use this.

In your question, the expression creates a dictionary

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{ AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : @(AVAudioQualityMax) };
```

Similarly arrays which were created using `NSArray arrayWithArray` and other similar methods, can now be done easily

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"Hello", @"World"];
```

and you will not even need the `nil` sentinel.

More details here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Actually, it's not literally a literal, since the keys and values can be variables.  But it's the same basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

The @{ ... } syntax is a shorthand way of creating a NSDictionary introduced as part of Modern Objective-C. The syntax `@{@"key1": object1, @"key2": object2}` is just a shorthand for more verbose methods like `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` among a few others.

Comment: In other words: It's a *Godsend*. :)

Comment: Of course, under the covers, it's just executing a private form of `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys`.  It's just a more convenient way to write it.

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C and I beg to differ. I could actually read [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:aObject, key1 ,anotheObject, key2, nil]... now I can't even do that.

Comment: You can keep using that method if you want. Anyone with any experience, however, will likely prefer to have keys and values in the right order and not have a sentinel.