# What is the meaning of "at sign" in NSLog function

Tags: objective-c

what is the sign `@` for ?

I thought `NSLog("X =%i and Y= %i", _x, _y);` without `@` is meaningful enough.

```
- (void) print
{
    NSLog(@"X =%i and Y= %i", _x, _y);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c. second answer refers to strings

Comment: See "Creating and Converting String Objects" in Apple's [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html). Its used to create a `NSString` literal, and the string literal should be UTF-8.

Comment: I hate when good questions like this get down voted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than all the great answers from the link @giorashc gave in his comment, basically `@"stuff"` is the way to create an `NSString` object in cocoa. Even the dedicated method of `NSString` for creating a string asks for an `NSString` object.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:..]
```

The `@` symbol is also used as syntax-shortcuts to create `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictioary`... e.g. This: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2, nil]` is equel to: `@[obj1, obj2]`

Answer (score 0):

In Obj C the @ sign is required to indicate the beginning of a string constant.

```
NSString *txt = @"sample";
```

You're specifying a literal format string, so there you are...

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c using characters without '@' token denotes C type (char *) or (const char *). Adding prefix '@' token denotes an NSString literal.