# Why @ in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm coming to Objective-C from Java.  I gather Strings are:

```
NSString *greeting = @"Hello";
```

What I'm wondering is why do I need the `@` symbol, as opposed to just:

```
NSString *greeting = "Hello";
```

I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Comment: Because all the other characters were used.  (Which is the same reason that `@` is used in email addresses.)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749/what-does-the-symbol-represent-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

`"Hello"` is C string expression or in other words C array of char. `@"Hello"` is instance of class `NSString`.

So, this would be correct :

```
NSString *greeting = @"Hello";
char *greeting2 = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a real superset of C. as "Hello" is a C construct (c array of chars, aka C-String), it must be usable as that in Objective-C too. There-for to separate C-Strings from NSString objects, a symbol is needed to allow literal creation during compile time.

Actually the `@`-Symbol is used throughout Objective-C to distinguish Objective-C related things from C. (`@selector()`, `@[]`, `@{}`, `@try/@catch/@finally`)

Answer (score 1):

With `@"Hello"` you get an `NSString` literal, an object. With `"Hello"` you get a C string literal. Similarly, there is special syntax for creating `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSNumber` literals:

```
// Instantiate an array with objects a, b, c
NSArray *myArray = @[a, b, c];

// Instantiate a dictionary (a map) with k1, k2, k3 as keys and o1, o2, o3 a
NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{k1: o1, k2: o2, k3: o3};

// Instantiate a number with int 1234
NSNumber *myNumber = @1234;
```

Source: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html